# Force 'Agenda' view in kendo ui Scheduler to display weekly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is there a way to force the Agenda View in Kendo ui scheduler to navigate by week when using the < > buttons in the navigation? Right now the buttons move the Agenda view by day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple but working solution:

```
navigate: function(e) {
    if(e.view === "agenda"){
        if(e.action === "next"){
            e.date.setDate(e.date.getDate() + 6);
        }
        if(e.action === "previous"){
            e.date.setDate(e.date.getDate() - 6);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is telerik dojo fiddle for you: http://dojo.telerik.com/IrAxO.